# Hex string to IP (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ip

I'm trying to query a database that shows IP addresses in the following format:
IP: 00000000000000000000ffff0a031b5e

I tried doing several conversions online but couldn't get it, then I realized that the following characters are automatically getting inserted into the field:  **00000000000000000000ffff**

The actual IP value is this: **0a031b5e** which is 10.3.27.94

I was able to find the conversion by using this (Hex to IP) site http://sami.on.eniten.com/hex2ip/?

now the question is how to do the same conversion is SQL.
Has anyone come across something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to turn this guy's code into a function that will return the IP: http://gursethi.blogspot.com/2010/09/convert-hex-string-to-ip-address.html

Comment: That's an IPv4 address mapped in the IPv6 address space. The IPv6 address is `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a03:1b5e`. What is the data type of the field?